# Do you guys know of a book that involves detectives, disembodied brains, and conspiracies?

Tags: story-identification

This was a cheap novel told in the first-person about a futuristic detective who searches for a missing person.

He finds out that the government uses disembodied brains to control weapons, specifically tanks.

I read this book originally in English, in the late 80's or mid 90's. There was a tank on the cover.

Comment: Is there anything else you can add? Like, what language, where you read it, when you read it?